# Google Cloud MySQL replication to BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a GCP MySQL database and I want to replicate data into BigQuery.  Honestly not 100% sure if I have the correct approach but running into issues.

1. Created a new Cloud Data Fusion instance
2. Replication > + button > Create a replication job
3. Gave it a name
4. Selected MySQL
5. Entered host/port/database name/user/password
6. Cannot move forward

It appears to be that I don't have a JDBC plugin name.  However, I cannot figure out where to create it.  Also since this is making a direct connection do I need to forward the Cloud Data Fusion IP address to the database's firewall?  If so where do I find the IP address of the Cloud fusion?

If there is a better solution feel free to point me to it.

Comment: I'm wondering (out loud) if BigQuery External Data Sources are not the answer .... see ...https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources

This seems to say that I can define a connection to MySQL from BigQuery and then execute a query against MySQL resulting in new tables in BQ.  No Data Fusion involved.

Comment: @Kolban that is great for querying data, I want data replication.  If I go down that road then I need to write all queries to move data from MySql to BigQuery.  Figure out what tables have been inserted/update/deletes.  More work than I was hoping for

Comment: What''s your process? The Kolban solution is great. You can read the data and insert them into a BigQuery table (Select Insert statements). If you want a realtime replication, I recommend you to have a look to Datastream, in GA since yesterday.

Comment: Have you seen https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery? With regards to using a JDBC plugin.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I do want real-time replication, however, I couldn't find anything that links GA to a GCP MySQL database to read the data.  Any links?

Comment: @RiccoD That link is what started me down Cloud Data Fusion.  Unless I am reading that link wrong it is configuring the JDBC plugin to a MySQL database in a docker VM.  I already have a database in Google Cloud SQL that is not being moved to a docker VM.

Comment: Does it help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nL4UuFQKy0

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that looks fine, however, this leads to a problem with the Dataflow template and what I am doing.  I am going to post a new question as it is too different then this original question.